# ios shortcuts : Extract dictionnary key from choose list

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts

I have a dictionary as an entry for a list of choices :

[image: Input dictionnary]

I can select the desired item from the list but I don't know how to extract its key ?
Actually, when I select an item it just returns the title.

[image: Select list from dictionnary]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can select "key" for the variable method, and put a Get Item from List block below it.

[[image: Siri Shortcuts]

With this it will return 2345.